# Trigger only fires 50% of the time

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to write a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger to keep a `tsvector` column updated.

What is odd to me is that the trigger fires 50% of the time. I tested it in `psql` and although `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` lists the trigger firing all the time, I only see the value changing the second time I re-issue the same update.

Additionally, on `INSERT` nothing changes.

**This is how the trigger is defined:**

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION "update_reading_list_document"()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.reading_list_document := (
      SELECT to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(body_markdown)) ||
             to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(cached_tag_list)) ||
             to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(title)) ||
             to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(coalesce(organizations.name, ''))) ||
             to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(coalesce(users.name, ''))) ||
             to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(coalesce(users.username, ''))) AS tsvector
      FROM articles
      LEFT OUTER JOIN organizations ON organizations.id = articles.organization_id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.id = articles.user_id
      WHERE articles.id = NEW.id
    );
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_reading_list_document BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "articles"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE "update_reading_list_document"();
```

I'm trying to update the column `reading_list_document` by joining bits and pieces from other columns in the same table and two other related tables.

**This is what happens in `psql`:**

```sql
Forem_development=# update articles set title = 'superamazing' where id = 10012; select id, title, reading_list_document from articles where id = 10012;
UPDATE 1
Time: 6.524 ms
┌───────┬──────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│  id   │    title     │                                                                   reading_list_document                                                                    │
├───────┼──────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ 10012 │ superamazing │ 'again':11,13 'and':12 'been':7 'edited':10 'for':9 'genericword':15 'help':4,14 'is':2 'pink':16 'rhymes':17 'the':3 'this':1 've':6 'waiting':8 'you':5  │
└───────┴──────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)

Time: 0.215 ms
Forem_development=# update articles set title = 'superamazing' where id = 10012; select id, title, reading_list_document from articles where id = 10012;
UPDATE 1
Time: 1.159 ms
┌───────┬──────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│  id   │    title     │                                                                    reading_list_document                                                                    │
├───────┼──────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ 10012 │ superamazing │ 'again':11,13 'and':12 'been':7 'edited':10 'for':9 'help':4,14 'is':2 'pink':16 'rhymes':17 'superamazing':15 'the':3 'this':1 've':6 'waiting':8 'you':5  │
└───────┴──────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)

Time: 0.205 ms
```

The first time I run the `UPDATE`, the content of the `tsvector` column does not change by taking into account the new `title`. The second time I run it, it works, the word `superamazing` replaced `genericword` in the document.

I double checked with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` which seems to be always running the trigger:

```sql
> explain analyze update articles set title = 'macos' where id = 10031;
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                            │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Update on articles  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=2447) (actual time=0.163..0.164 rows=0 loops=1)                               │
│   ->  Index Scan using articles_pkey on articles  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=2447) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=1 loops=1) │
│         Index Cond: (id = 10031)                                                                                                │
│ Planning Time: 0.158 ms                                                                                                         │
│ Trigger update_reading_list_document: time=0.108 calls=1                                                                        │
│ Execution Time: 0.207 ms                                                                                                        │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(6 rows)
```

Despite what `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` says for the `INSERT`, it won't trigger:

```sql
> explain analyze insert into articles (title, body_markdown, created_at, updated_at) values ('Not a title', 'not a body', now(), now());
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                            QUERY PLAN                                             │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Insert on articles  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=1189) (actual time=0.238..0.239 rows=0 loops=1) │
│   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=1189) (actual time=0.027..0.028 rows=1 loops=1)       │
│ Planning Time: 0.056 ms                                                                           │
│ Trigger for constraint fk_rails_2b371e3029: time=0.030 calls=1                                    │
│ Trigger for constraint fk_rails_7809a1a57d: time=0.003 calls=1                                    │
│ Trigger for constraint fk_rails_3d31dad1cc: time=0.003 calls=1                                    │
│ Trigger update_reading_list_document: time=0.080 calls=1                                          │
│ Execution Time: 0.396 ms                                                                          │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

> insert into articles (title, body_markdown, created_at, updated_at) values ('Not a title again', 'not a body again', now(), now()) returning id;
┌───────┐
│  id   │
├───────┤
│ 10034 │
└───────┘
INSERT 0 1
Time: 3.204 ms

> select id, title, reading_list_document from articles where id = 10034;
┌───────┬───────────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│  id   │       title       │ reading_list_document │
├───────┼───────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ 10034 │ Not a title again │ NULL                  │
└───────┴───────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need to access the column values from the `new` record, not from the table. In a before trigger, the row will not yet exist in the table (when doing an INSERT). So the SELECT will never return a row and thus the whole ts_vector expression will be null.

As there doesn't seem to be a direct link between users and organizations, I would suggest to split up populating of the vector into three steps.

You also need to deal with NULL values in the NEW record (e.g. in your sample INSERT, `cached_tag_list` will be NULL as you have not supplied a value for it).

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_reading_list_document()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
  l_org_vector tsvector;
  l_user_vector tsvector;
BEGIN
    -- populate from the NEW record
    NEW.reading_list_document := 
         to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(coalesce(NEW.body_markdown,''))) ||
         to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(coalesce(NEW.cached_tag_list,''))) ||
         to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(coalesce(NEW.title,'')));
             
    -- populate organization stuff
    SELECT to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(coalesce(organizations.name, '')))
       INTO l_org_vector
    FROM organizations 
    WHERE organizations.id = NEW.organization_id;
    
    IF l_org_vector IS NOT NULL THEN
      NEW.reading_list_document := NEW.reading_list_document || l_org_vector;
    END IF;
    
    -- populate users stuff
    SELECT to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(coalesce(users.name, ''))) ||
           to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(coalesce(users.username, ''))) 
        INTO l_user_vector
    FROM users 
    WHERE users.id = NEW.user_id;
    
    IF l_user_vector IS NOT NULL THEN
      NEW.reading_list_document := NEW.reading_list_document || l_user_vector;
    END IF;
    
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be working well. I'm finishing up writing some business logic and I also plan to test the solution presented in this other answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/289362/226575

Answer (score 3):

The immediate cause of the problem is that the values are not yet in the table, so querying the table won't find them.

That would be fixed by using the `NEW` values instead:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(coalesce(NEW.body_markdown, ''))) ||
       to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(coalesce(NEW.cached_tag_list, ''))) ||
       to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(coalesce(NEW.title, ''))) ||
       to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(coalesce(organizations.name, ''))) ||
       to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(coalesce(users.name, ''))) ||
       to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent(coalesce(users.username, ''))) AS
   INTO NEW.reading_list_document
FROM organizations
   CROSS JOIN users
WHERE users.id = NEW.user_id
  AND organizations.id = NEW.organization_id;
```

The deeper problem is that changes in the related rows on `organizations` and `users` won't be reflected in your `tsvector`.  Also, if you restore the database from a dump, the tables won't be restores in the order you expect, and you could end up with values missing.

Don't do that. Use `tsvector`s on all three tables and search that way.

Comment: Hi Laurenz! Thanks for the tips! I plan to rely on business level callbacks in the interim, to keep the `tsvector` column up to date with the related tables. It's not the cleanest of solutions but with extensive testing of the business logic it should scale for a while.

Thanks for reminding me about when the trigger can see the table data

Comment: It is not about scaling, it is about data integrity. After restoring from a backup, your data may be changed (for example if `users` is restored after `articles`).